# Como validar entrada de dados de um web Service?

Tags: c#, web-service

Qual a melhora maneira de validar a chamada de um WebService ? Explico:
Tenho um WebService que tem como o Request uma String de tamanho variado e que retorna a mesma string Formatada, exemplo:

String de entrada:

> "ST STN, CONJUNTO J, * LOJAS T-40 /T41, - TER-REO, SHOPPING &
>   BOULEVARD KM 28,5 VALOR 450.00 CENTRAL."

E que deve retornar a String no seguinte formato:

> "ST STN CONJUNTO J LOJAS T40 T41 TERREO SHOPPING E BOULEVARD KM **28,5
>   450.00** CENTRAL"

Obs.: Campos decimais preservar o **Ponto** e **Vírgula**.

Ou seja, remover todos os **Caracteres Especiais** com **EXCEÇÃO** onde for **Valores Decimais**, como por exemplo 28,5 e 450.00.

Já tentei fazer com **Regex.Replace** mas sem sucesso e estou a fazer com **Replace nativo do C#** , porém com Replace fica muito complexo conforme um trecho abaixo, exemplo:

Aqui substitui alguns caracteres (problema não abrange todos caracteres):

```
string _texto = pTexto.Trim().Replace("S/A","SA").Replace("s.a.", "SA").Replace("S.A.","SA").Replace("S A", "SA").Replace("'","")
                                        .Replace("-", " ").Replace("&", "E").ToUpper().Replace("(","")
                                        .Replace(")","") .Replace("/", " ").Trim().Replace(";", "").Replace("N/C", "NC").Replace("\"","")
                                        .Replace("*","").Replace("+", "");
```

E com o Regex não consegui, pois se retiro **todos** os acentos e caracteres da frase, os valores **Decimais** perdem a **Vírgula** ou o **Ponto**

```
String padrao = @"(?i)(,|.)?[^A-Z0-9]\s"; 
String padrao = @"(?i)[^0-9A-Z]\s]";

Regex rg = new Regex(_texto, " ");

var arrayTexto = resultado.Normalize(NormalizationForm.Formd).toCharArray();
                    foreach(char letter in arrayTexto) { 
                        if (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(letter) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark) sb.Append(letter); 
                        }
```

Qual a melhor maneira de validar essa string?

Answer (score 0):

Em vez de receber uma unica string, "quebre" ela em varias partes, assim você pode usar uma logica para remover os caracteres  da primeira parte :

```
"ST STN, CONJUNTO J, * LOJAS T-40 /T41, - TER-REO, SHOPPING & BOULEVARD";
```

Depois outra logica para verificar as partes :

```
"KM 28,5" "VALOR 450.00 CENTRAL"
```